# windows classic theme on windows 7 using java 7 u45 and greater

Tags: java, swing, java-7, windows-7-x64, jnlp

I have a Swing application that gets deployed on clients machine using a JNLP. Earlier we were using Java 5/6 to run the application on client machine and did support only pre Windows Vista operating systems. We also force the application to have "Windows Classic" look and feel by introducing `-swing.noxp=true` parameter in the JNLP file. This made sure that the application always had a classic look and feel.

But, now with the new requirement we have to support Java 7 and Windows 7/8 as well. In the Java 7u45 document I read that `-swing.noxp` is no longer supported. This eventually means that I can not use this parameter for the application to default to classic look and feel.

I tried launching the application with Windows 7 and Java 7u51 without the "-swing.noxp" parameter. This made the application look like Windows 7 default theme which gave a weird look and feel to the application (I can post the comparative snap shots if need be).

My question here is, does Java 7 have some parameter (in place of `-swing.noxp`) which will do the trick for me(because client want the application to have the same look and feel as pre Java 7 upgrade.)?

I know I can change the PLAFs and all but that is a huge code change. I am looking for something simple and similar to `-swing.noxp`

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The framework is called Swing, not Swings. I guess it's a typo, but the parameter consequently is called `-swing.noxp` not `-swings.noxp`. You should be able to turn on the "Windows Classic LAF" using `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel")` before you initialize your first Swing component. But this will look very strange unless you also turn on the old-fashioned look in Windows itself. But to be honest: I would immediately stop using an application that _forced_ such an outdated UI on me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes you are correct it was a typo and the frame work is indead called Swing. thanks for correcting me there. I have also tried the option mentioned by you. But I failed miserably as the Windows theme was Windows 7. Even we want to move on to the new look and feel but the client is interested in classic look and feel and says "Old in Gold". (on the funny side) Probably i will try to change the appliation to latest look and feel after he is dead and some one young take over.. hahaha..

Comment: "*failed miserably*" is not a valid Java error message

Comment: What i meant was the look and feel was all out of place. Probably a screen grab will make it more clear to you. Can you please help me on how to attach a screen grab to this question?